# request API data from a row name that has a numeric value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, xmlhttprequest

I want to request data via the XMLHttpRequest from stockdata.org by using the following code:

```
var requestURL = 'https://api.stockdata.org/v1/data/currency/latest?symbols=BTCUSD&api_token=[API_KEY]';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  console.log(request.response.data[0]);
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that after the row "data[0]" there is a row with the value 0 as name. When I use the code;

```
console.log(request.response.data[0].0);
```

I get a syntax error.

This is the table that I am fetching data from:

[image]

I would like to know how I can fetch the symbol with the value "BTCUSD".

```
console.log(request.response.data[0].symbol);
```

also didn't work unfortunately

Comment: `request.response.data[0][0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a row with the value 0 as name

`data` appears to be an array *of* arrays and I don't believe you can index arrays like that. Have you tried this instead?

```js
console.log(request.response.data[0][0]);
```

As for accessing `BTCUSD`, I believe you would just want this, for similar reasons:

```js
// Note the TWO [0] here because there's TWO arrays
request.response.data[0][0].symbol
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, that works! I'm new to js, I did try data [0, 0] but seems thats not the correct syntax indeed. Many thanks!